# JavaScript OOP : running two instances of a method within a single Object simultaneously

Tags: javascript, json, oop, xmlhttprequest, prototype

So, I have an object `Async` that creates a request for (in this case) a JSON object from github.

There is a method `Async.createList` that creates a list of all instances of a specific attribute from the github JSON object. It works just fine when `Async.createList` is called once, but I want to be able to create multiple lists from different target attributes from the same request, and this is where it fails.

Ideally, the lists would be appended to the `Async.lists` object so that they can be used outside of the `Async` object. Right now, when I call `Async.createList` multiple times, only the last call appends to `Async.lists`.

```
function Async(address) {
    this.req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.address = address
}

Async.prototype = {

    lists : {},

    create : function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        this.req.open('GET', this.address, true);
        this.req.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    dump(this.responseText);
                    if (callback != null) callback()
                } else {
                    dump("COULD NOT LOAD \n");
                }
            }
        }
        this.req.send(null);
    },

    response : function(json) {
        return json == true ? JSON.parse(this.req.responseText) : this.req.responseText    
    },

    createList : function(target) {
        var self = this
        var bits = []
          this.req.onload = function(){  
            var list = self.response(true)
            for(obj in list){
                bits.push(self.response(true)[obj][target])
            }
            self.lists[target] = bits
        }
    },


}
```

I am creating the object and calling the methods like this:

```
var github = new Async("https://api.github.com/users/john/repos")
github.create();
github.createList("name");
github.createList("id");
```

And then trying:

```
github.lists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-assigning the function for `this.req.onload` every time you call `github.createList`.

i understand you want to do things after the request is loaded using `req.onload`, but you are assigning a new function everytime, so the last assigned function will be called.

You need to remove the `onload` function within `Async.createList`

Call `github.createList("name");` only after the request is loaded as follows

```
var github = new Async("https://api.github.com/users/john/repos")

github.create();

github.req.onload = function () {

    github.createList("name");
    github.createList("id");
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the answer I gave, but slightly different! Check mine out. If you mention that I need to remove the onload function within `Async.createList` I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is painfully simple. All I needed to do was get rid of the `onload` function within `Async.createList` and simple call `Async.createList` in the callback of `Async.create`

```
createList : function(target) {
    var self = this
    var bits = []

        var list = self.response(true)
        for(obj in list){
            bits.push(self.response(true)[obj][target])
        }
        self.lists[target] = bits

},
```

Using this to instantiate:

```
var github = new Async("https://api.github.com/users/john/repos")
github.create(callback);

function callback(){
    github.createList("name");
    github.createList("id");
}
```